# send http request to an electronjs application via an api

Tags: http, electron

Is it possible to send a http request to an electronjs application thats active on a pc?

example

if i create an mobile application with a button, the button should send a request to an server than the server sends a request to the application thats active on the pc, like to press button a or b

if so whats the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achive this you would need an active client on the electron application and a backend server running.

You can make use of socket.io to achieve this. Socket.Io is very simple to learn and its a great tool to know how to use.

https://socket.io/

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this? are there any examples i could look at?